# Show $\left(\frac{1}{1+x^{2}t^{2}}\right)\left(\frac{1}{1+y^{2}t^{2}}\right)$ is integrable on $[0,1]\times[0,1]\times\mathbb{R}^{+}$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

> Let $f(a,b) = \frac{1}{1+a^{2}b^{2}}$ be defined on $[0,1]\times\mathbb{R}^{+}$. Define $g(x,y,t) = f(x,t)f(y,t)$ where $(x,y,t)\in [0,1]\times[0,1]\times\mathbb{R}^{+}$. Show g is integrable on $[0,1]\times[0,1]\times\mathbb{R}^{+}$.
> [The integral here is the Lebesgue integral]

My approach is as follows. Since $g$ is nonnegative, by Tonelli's Theorem, we can write
$$\int_{[0,1]\times[0,1]\times\mathbb{R}^{+}}g(x,y,t)dxdydt = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{+}}\int_{[0,1]}\left(\frac{1}{1+y^{2}t^{2}}\right)\int_{[0,1]}\left(\frac{1}{1+x^{2}t^{2}}\right)dxdydt$$
$$= \int_{\mathbb{R}^{+}}\frac{\arctan(t)}{t}\int_{[0,1]}\left(\frac{1}{1+y^{2}t^{2}}\right)dydt = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{+}}\frac{\arctan^{2}(t)}{t^{2}}dt$$

Since $\arctan(t)$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}^{+}$, we only have to care about the $\frac{1}{t^{2}}$ term, but $\frac{1}{t^{2}}$ is not integrable on $\mathbb{R^{+}}$. Therefore, I don't know how to show $g$ is integrable on $[0,1]\times[0,1]\times\mathbb{R}^{+}$.

Is my approach correct? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Plot the integrand on $[0,1]$. The numerator $\text{arctan}^2(t)$ is going to $0$ fast enough near $t=0$.

Comment: $1/t^2$ is not integrable on $\mathbb R^+$ because of its divergent behavior near $0$. $\lim_{t\to0} \arctan t/t=1$ make the divergence won't happen.

Comment: For small $t$, $\arctan t \approx t$.

Comment: Thanks! I think I got it.